Problem NonLinearModelFit
I am running a two year old notebook it does not recognize the property "MeanPredictionErrors" anymore. It is also not listed in "properties".
On the otherhand "MeanPredictionConfidenceIntervalTable" gives an answer but is also not listed as properties. Did I miss something?

Confirm it in 14.1 on Windows 10, trying data = {{1., 0.75}, {2., 0.89}, {3., 0.42}, {4., 0.99}, {5.,      0.84}, {6., 0.34}, {7., 0.83}, {8., 0.93}, {9., 0.76}, {10.,      0.11}}; nlm = NonlinearModelFit[   data, {Exp[a + b x^2], b < -1/2}, {{a, 0}, {b, -1}}, x].

You can get the standard errors with nlm["MeanPredictions"][[All, 3]] in 14.1.

Thanks for reporting this. The update shouldn't have broken the "MeanPredictionErrors" property.
